# Order by and top on grouped rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How do I order by date desc my grouped items and get top 20?

For example: The table Orderproduct have OrderID, ProductId, Date, Price, I want to group by ProductId and sort each grouped by Date desc then get top 20 and avg(price).

On LINQ, this is how (but the sql generated is very dirty and the performance is very bad).

```
OrderProduct
    .GroupBy(g => g.ProductId)
    .Select(s => new{ s.Key, Values = s.OrderByDescending(o => o.Date).Take(20) })
    .Select(s => new{ Avg = s.Values.Average(a => a.Price) } )
```

Comment: If you group by `ProductID` what aggregation do you want on the other fields?

Comment: I want the min, max, avg from top 20 sorted prices

Comment: OK so you want the price aggregated, but what about date and orderid?  Exclude those?  you need to do something with them.

Comment: OrderId i will ignore and date i will use just to sort

Comment: Well you need to use date in  your result set if you want to sort by it...

Comment: Yes, but how can I do this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question this might work for you.

```
select ProductId,
       avg(price) as AvgPrice
from ( select ProductId,
              Price,
              row_number() over(partition by ProductId order by [Date] desc) as rn
       from Orderproduct
     ) as O
where rn <= 20
group by ProductId
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on  your comments, this may work:

```
SELECT  [Date], 
        ProductID, 
        MIN(Price) as Min, 
        MAX(Price) as MAX, 
        AVG(Price) as Avg
FROM OrderProduct o1
WHERE [Date] IN (SELECT TOP 20 [Date] 
                 FROM OrderProduct o2
                 WHERE o1.productid = o2.productid)
GROUP BY [Date], ProductID
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Comment: No, i want to filter grouped results, you are grouping all and I need to group just top 20 sorted by date

Comment: @Alexandre - you probably should make really clear what you want, then, because it's not clear at all currently.

Comment: For example productId 19 has 200 registers, I just want to know max(price) on top 20 results sorted by date

Comment: Is the date range going to be different for each `ProductId`?

Comment: No, just top 20 more recently

Comment: OK try the edited answer.  I added a correlated subquery to limit to top 20 dates per product.

Answer (score 0):

Does this get you want you want for ALL rows?  I understand you ONLY want the top 20 for each product.  I just don't want to spend the time on top 20 if this is not correct.  And does top 20 mean 20 highest prices, or 20 most recent dates, or 20 most recent (can there be more than one per day per productID?)?

```
    SELECT [ProductID], [Date], [Price]
    FROM [OrderProduct] 
    ORDER BY [ProductID] asc, [Date] desc, [Price] desc 
    COMPUTE AVG(Price) BY [ProductID];
```